# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi programa en C++ no se cierre al final de la última linea?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

¿Qué línea de código debería añadir para que no se cierre la consola al terminar el programa y me permita ver el resultado? Adjunto un ejemplo

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int edad;
cout<<"Introduzca su edad: ";
cin>>edad;
if((edad>=18)&&(edad<=25)){
    cout<<"Su edad esta en el rango de 18 y 25 anos";   
}
else{
    cout<<"Su edad no esta en dicho rango";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: De la misma manera que usas "cin" para esperar que se introduzca un texto, puedes usarlo al final del código

Comment: Puedes utilizar `system("pause");`

Comment: He probado la respuesta de "getchar()" pero finalmente lo que me ha funcionado ha sido el "system("pause")" que ha propuesto @DevMind.

Comment: Habitualmente, `system("pause")` no funcionará en lo que no sea Windows. Si se trata de un ejercicio para un profesor, mejor asegurarse de usar estándares que vayan a funcionar en cualquier sitio. 

En inglés esto se respondió en <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776262/pause-console-in-c-program>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hago esta respuesta en base a mi comentario para quedar constancia y así ayudar a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema o necesidad.

Puedes utilizar `system("pause");` para que una vez tu programa finalice, hacer una pausa y poder ver el resultado en la consola.

Ejemplo completo:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int edad;
    cout<<"Introduzca su edad: ";
    cin>>edad;

    if((edad>=18)&&(edad<=25)){
        cout<<"Su edad esta en el rango de 18 y 25 anos";   
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Su edad no esta en dicho rango";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a utilizar la función getchar() -la cuál lee un carácter- antes del `return`. Ésto hará que la terminal sólo se cierre al presionar una tecla y podrá así ver la ejecución del programa.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/